# If the MH370 black box did sink to 15000 ft, how long would it have taken?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water, drag, buoyancy

I have been following MH370 on the news just as everyone and latest reports seem to indicate that the black-box could be found. A recent info-graphic http://t.co/lyBBE9C2hF shows the insurmountable depth of the oceans and how the black-box could have sunk 15,000 ft! I wonder how long it would have taken for it to sunk to the bottom of the sea-bed? What is the equation of motion for a sinking object at sea, ignoring under-water currents?

Comment: The Force Body diagram is going to include Gravitational force acting downwards of course, and the buoyant force acting upwards. Just need the latter force in terms of what you have.

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/lindrg.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant equation is the kinematics with [linear drag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_%28physics%29#Very_low_Reynolds_numbers%3a_Stokes.27_drag). In this case, there is a resistant force that acts opposite gravity (i.e., upwards) and is linear to the velocity at which it travels:
$$
\mathbf F_D=-b\mathbf v
$$
where $b$ is some fluid- and object-dependent constant.

Using Newton's 2nd law,
$$
m\ddot{\mathbf x}=m\mathbf g - b\dot{\mathbf x}
$$
If we assume a one dimensional case,
$$x(t) = \frac{c_1 m e^{-b t/m}}{b}+\frac{g m t}{b}+c_2$$

If you know what the constants are (depends on assumptions at the boundaries, e.g. was it stationary or moving), then you can figure out the time it took.

Comment: Is it posible to estimate the constants?

Comment: Yes good answer, but what might the bounds be on your solution given the piece containing the box is smaller than the 777 and no larger than the box itself. And how deep is the Indian Ocean?

Comment: Assume depth to be 15000 ft. according to the infographic link in original question. Also for the moment assume that the black box was stationary before it sank. Is it now possible to find the constants?

Comment: Well $c_2$ could be either 15,000 ft or 0 ft depending on your reference point. I'll think a bit more about what $c_1$ should be.

Answer (score 0):

You say, ignore currents and I assume, other extraneous factors.

If that is the case, then, considering a hydrostatic balance in the water column where z is the vertical coordinate. Then, the motion of a water parcel with density, $\rho$, displaced upwards by a distance, $\Delta z$, in a fluid with a reference density, $\rho_0$, is governed by

$\rho_0 \frac{d^2\Delta z}{dt^2} = g \frac{d \bar{\rho}}{dt^2} \Delta z$

I am confident you will be able to deduce the rest.